# LaTeX: \newenvironment with only one optional arg (and no mandatory)

Tags: latex

I try to set a new environment within a class that would take only an optional argument, or none.

This would be used like this :

```
\begin{myEnv}          -->  "Label:"
```

or

```
\begin{myEnv}[myLabel] -->  "Label: myLabel"
```

I try to define this environment with basic macros. I would rather not to use xparse package.

I have found several examples of \newenvironment with an optional argument together with a mandatory one. But I do not need a mandatory argument!

Is there a way to do this with \newenvironment or \def macros ?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 7):

No problem, just declare the environment with one argument, and make that optional:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newenvironment*{myEnv}[1][]{%
  Label: #1%
  \par
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \par
  end%
  \par
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\begin{document}
\begin{myEnv}
  abc
\end{myEnv}
\begin{myEnv}[myLabel]
  abc
\end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```